# Floating Div Over An Image

Tags: html, css, css-float, z-index

I'm having trouble floating a div over an image. Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

```css
    .container {
       border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
       width: 200px;
       height: 200px;
    }
    .tag {
       float: left;
       position: relative;
       left: 0px;
       top: 0px;
       z-index: 1000;
       background-color: #92AD40;
       padding: 5px;
       color: #FFFFFF;
       font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
       <div class="tag">Featured</div>
       <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x200">
    </div>
```

In this image:

[image]

I want the "Featured" box to float over top of the image but instead it seems to "clear" the float and cause the image to wrap to the next line, as though it was displaying as a block element. Unfortunately, I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dChUR/3/  something like this? Add position:relative to container, and position:absolute to box...

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Never fails, once I post the question to SO, I get some enlightening "aha" moment and figure it out. The solution:

```css
    .container {
       border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
       width: 200px;
       height: 200px;
       position: relative;
    }
    .tag {
       float: left;
       position: absolute;
       left: 0px;
       top: 0px;
       z-index: 1000;
       background-color: #92AD40;
       padding: 5px;
       color: #FFFFFF;
       font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
       <div class="tag">Featured</div>
       <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x200">
</div>
```

The key is the container has to be positioned **relative** and the tag positioned **absolute**.

Comment: hey I want to do the same thing and also make the height of the div to be the same as image, but height: 100% does not work for that (probably because of absolute positoining)

Answer (score 22):

Change your positioning a bit:

```
.container {
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position:relative;
}
.tag {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dChUR/5/)**

You need to set relative positioning on the container and then absolute on the inner tag div. The inner tag's absolute positioning will be with respect to the outer relatively positioned div. You don't even need the z-index rule on the tag div.

Answer (score 6):

Actually just adding margin-bottom: -20px; to the tag class fixed it right up.

http://jsfiddle.net/dChUR/7/

Being block elements, div's naturally have defined borders that they try not to violate. To get them to layer for images, which have no content beside the image because they have no closing tag, you just have to force them to do what they do not want to do, like violate their natural boundaries.

```
.container {
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  }
.tag {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: green;
  z-index: 1000;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
  }
```

Another toue to take would be to create div's using an image as the background, and then place content where ever you like.

```
<div id="imgContainer" style="
         background-image: url("foo.jpg"); 
         background-repeat: no-repeat; 
         background-size: cover; 
         -webkit-background-size: cover; 
         -mox-background-size: cover; 
         -o-background-size: cover;">
  <div id="theTag">BLAH BLAH BLAH</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Right, negative margin with position relative work well. Properties "top", ”left" and "z-index" are not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You've got the right idea. Looks to me like you just need to change `.tag`'s `position:relative` to `position:absolute`, and add `position:relative` to `.container`.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with **relative** position.

### But why isn't your code working?

An element with `position:relative` keeps it's position and also still affects all other following elements. That's the reason why your div won't overlap the image by just using **z-index**.

You'll still need to position the div element with, for example: `top:-28px` where the amount would be the height of the element with `tag` class.

> **Note:** `top` has no effect on non-positioned elements. It works with `absolute`, `relative` and `sticky`.

If you add `top:-28px` to the tag element it will only overlap the image if the `z-index` it has a higher number. This is the importance of `z-index` in this case.

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.tag {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 1;
   float: left;
   padding: 5px;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   font-weight: bold;
   background-color: #92AD40;
}
img{
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
  top:-28px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id='tag' class="tag">Featured</div>
  <img id='img' src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUDax.png">
</div>
```

### If you want to play a bit with this concepts

I added some JS code to toggle between different styles

```js
const tag = document.getElementById('tag')
const img =  document.getElementById('img')
const label1 = document.getElementById('label1')
const label2 = document.getElementById('label2')

function togglePosition(){
  if(!tag.style.position){
    tag.style.position = 'relative'
    img.style.position = 'relative'
    label1.innerHTML = 'Relative position added'
  }
  else{
    tag.style.position = null
    img.style.position = null
    label1.innerHTML = 'Add relative position'
  }
}

function toggleZindex(){
   if(!tag.style.zIndex){
    tag.style.zIndex = '1'
    img.style.zIndex = '0'
    label2.innerHTML = 'z-index  (1 and 0) added to elements'
  }
  else{
    tag.style.zIndex = null
    img.style.zIndex = null
    label2.innerHTML = 'Add z-index to elements'
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  margin-top:20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.tag {
   float: left;
   padding: 5px;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   font-weight: bold;
   background-color: #92AD40;
}
img{
  top:-28px;
}
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' onclick='togglePosition()'/> 
<label id='label1'>Add relative position</label>
<br/>
<input type='checkbox' onclick='toggleZindex()'/> 
<label id='label2'>Add z-index to elements</label>

<div class="container">
  <div id='tag' class="tag">Featured</div>
  <img id='img' src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUDax.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you might consider using the Relative and Absolute positining.

```
`.container {  
position: relative;  
}  
.tag {     
position: absolute;   
}`
```

I have tested it there, also if you want it to change its position use this as its margin:

`top: 20px;

left: 10px;`

It will place it 20 pixels from top and 10 pixels from left; but leave this one if not necessary.