# Placing div over image - how to control float behavior

Tags: css

I have followed the instructions at [floating-div-over-an-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339549/floating-div-over-an-image), and while things are working ok, I am trying to better control the behavior of the search box and the button. You can see the page I am working on [here](http://www.dev.pfp-consortium.org)

There is a search box on the header image towards the upper right. The CSS for the search box div as follows

```
.search-box{
    z-index: 500;
    width: 50%;
    border: 0px none;
    top: 0px;
    float: right;
    left: 40%;
    position: absolute !important;
}
```

You'll see that there is a search button to the right of the search box. When the browser window is made narrower, that search button jumps below, even when there is space to the right. I am trying to force that button to stay to the right.

Any tips on how you would achieve the behavior I described? I have tried variations of the float property in the CSS above, but that is not getting me what I need. Maybe I am not applying the correct CSS selector?

Regards

Comment: Please provide all the code required to reproduce the issue in the question itself.

Comment: Check ,my answer below http://stackoverflow.com/a/32394161/2006386

Answer (score 1):

Just change your `.search-box` css for property `width:100%`

It is **WORKING**

```
.search-box {
width:100%;
}
```

let me know if it is helpful

Answer (score 1):

In class (.search-box) the width was 40% so it was not getting enough room for the search box and button to display in line.
You Just need to replace the below css and it will work in all resolution.

```
.search-box{


    border: 0 none;
     position: absolute !important;
     text-align: right;
     width: 100%;
     z-index: 500;

}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. What would be really useful is if the left edge of the box would move to the left as the window becomes narrower. As I have it now (I specified right:-30% to get the location how I wanted), for the most part it is fine, but really narrow widths have the search extending beyond the header image. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes it worked, but giving (right :10%) it will put a scroll bar below the page.You need to replace the below code to remove the scroll bar .search-box {
  border: 0 none;
  left: 120px;
  position: absolute !important;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 500;
}

Comment: Also for the responsive you can add this media query in your css file @media screen and (max-width:767px){.search-box{left:0;}
}

Answer (score 0):

The `#k2ModuleBox125` div has a 40% width which is causing the search button to wrap to the next line when the search bar increases in size.

You can easily fix this by looking into the style rules of the `#k2ModuleBox125` div.

Comment: The below fixes seem to have worked, but I will see what this does, thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is happening because .search-box has its width in % give it minimal width, and position it to the right instead of left, and you should be just fine.

.search-box {
        min-width:XXpx;
        right: 0;
        left: auto;
    }