# Why won't my text align over the centre of the image?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align my header text in the middle of the page, over the image. The image is aligned in the centre, but the text is to the left of the page.

[image: Here is how it looks.]

I tried to copy [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339549/floating-div-over-an-image) solution, but I'm obviously not doing something right. Any help would be really appreciated.
HTML:

```
    <header>
        <div class="tag">
            <h1>Some text here</h1>
            <h3>And more text here</h3>
        </div>
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/900x300">
    </header>
```

CSS:

```
    header {
      height: 200px;
      line-height: 50px;
      text-align: center;
      background: #303e49;
      position: relative;
    }

    .tag {
         text-align: center;
         background: #303e49;
         position: absolute;

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1st you shouldn't tagged jquery cause its css

2nd  add left 0 and right 0 to your absolute element to get the full width of the contain div

```
.tag {
         text-align: center;
         background: #303e49;
         position: absolute;
         left: 0;
         right: 0;
         z-index : 1;
    }
```

Comment: But now I cant see my image behind it?

Comment: That did it, appreciate the help.

Comment: @drminnaar you Welcome .. Good Luck to you :)