# How to position div over image in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a page with an image and a header at the top, where you can leave the site. The problem is that when I scroll down, the image goes above the navbar.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339549/floating-div-over-an-image) question and saw that you can use `z-index` to make the navbar appear at the top of the page. I added the following code

```
.navbar {

    z-index: 1000;

}
```

That didn't work, the image still went over the navbar when I scrolled.

I tried changing the `z-index` of the image to -1000, and also adding `!important` to both of the CSS properties, and it still didn't work.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Can you provide your code (HTML + CSS) inside a fiddle?

Comment: Sadly not, as I am not developing the site, simply making a mod for it.

Comment: Without seeing any code, it's hard to know. But a shot in the dark - try adding position: relative; to the .navbar class and see if that helps

Comment: Just tried making the position relative, it may work but also completely wrecks the look of the site.

Comment: Oops, my bad. That's what I actually meant. Thanks

Comment: Note: z-index **only works on positioned elements** (position: absolute, position: relative, position: fixed, or position: sticky).



Source: [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Comment: Position absolute made the site look wrong again, fixed does look fine but the image still goes on top.

Comment: a fiddle would help a lot or at least paste your code in your answer so i can understand what you want

Comment: As I've said, I'm not sure I'm allowed to distribute the code as it's not my site, but I'll try to make a similar setup soon.