# Preventing image context menu from opening in Firefox and iOS not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, dom-events

I want to be able to prevent the context menu (In Firefox: "Copy link, share link, share image, open image in new tab, save image, copy image location") in React from opening when holding down a tap on an image in Firefox mobile and in Safari on iOS - but the code below, hobbled together from a few other SO answers, isn't working.

```
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('contextmenu', function (e) {
            // do something here...
            e.preventDefault();
        }, false);

        function absorbEvent_(event) {
            var e = event || window.event;
            e.preventDefault && e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation && e.stopPropagation();
            e.cancelBubble = true;
            e.returnValue = false;
            return false;
        }

        function preventLongPressMenu(node) {
            node.ontouchstart = absorbEvent_;
            node.ontouchmove = absorbEvent_;
            node.ontouchend = absorbEvent_;
            node.ontouchcancel = absorbEvent_;
        }

        function init() {
            preventLongPressMenu(document.getElementById('Image'));
        }
    </script>
```

What can I do? I'm using the code above in the index.html file, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: I was able to get a makeshift fix put into place: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339549/floating-div-over-an-image but would still like to know if it's possible to do it using event handlers.

Comment: Solution does not work fully in Safari, user is still able to select image but no context menu.